# How to make php website more secure

Tags: php

I found this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703449/how-to-prevent-php-files-from-being-downloaded-and-what-are-some-ways-someone-c) but right now I can't even access my php pages.

Index page works good. I have initial page that I pull via index.php file:

```
<?php

    include ("home.html");

?>
```

That works good.

But when I try to open this page:

```
<a href="our_projects.php" id='text'>
```

it causes this error:

Forbidden

```
You don't have permission to access /our_projects.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Because of settings I've added:

```
# In case there is no PHP, deny access to php files (for safety)
<IfModule !php5_module>
    <FilesMatch "\.(php|phtml)$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# the following should be added if you want to parse .php and .phtml file as PHP
# .phps will add syntax highlighting to the file when requesting it with a browser
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phtml .phps
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

My question how to prevent download php files outside, but in the same time allow browser to show content.

The main reason why I don't want PHP files to be read by someone is prevent reading some secure data like passwords to data base and etc.

Also I want to drop displaying .php in address line. I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address), but the address line still contains .php in a path.

Comment: It could simply be that you're not using php5, but php7 instead. Anyway, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387978/how-to-secure-php-files-from-being-downloaded The answer won't prevent others from gaining there hands on your code, but it will prevent them from gaining their hands on sensitive data.

Comment: @icecub, thanks, sorry I am not an php developer, so maybe need to look at some tutorial first.

Comment: No problem. If you want some more in depth help later in the future, feel free to contact me (email is on my profile). I'm more than happy to spend of couple of hours with you teaching php :)

Comment: @icecub, oh really! cool!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally say that such a security matter is rather useless. In all of the many, many websites I've built. I've never used any of these.

The best way I know of to prevent people from getting into places where you don't want them to go, is to bunch all of your classes into one folder and deny access to said folder from the outside. Then, you use one file in the root (index.php or so) to call upon said files through the requested URL. This would also give you user-friendly URL's.

A little bit of object-oriënted coding should take care of most security issues.

I'll give you a working example of such a feat here:

### Your root files:

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
#Request index.php and put a GET parameter 'request'
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then, from your **index.php**, include your main-class and routing

```
  require_once 'application/main.php';
  require_once 'application/routing.php';
```

### Your unreachable files:

Put these in a subdirectory, for example, /application/
**.htaccess:**

```
#This will deny access from any outside source.
#You reach these files through index.php
deny from all
```

**Main class**

```
 class main
  {
    public $someVar;

    public function setSomeVar(){
      $this->someVar = "I can get into the main class,
                        and shall use it for global functions!";
    }
}
```

**The requested page class: home.php**

```
class home extends main
{
  public function renderTemplate(){
    //You can reach the main's functions from here
    //You could create a rendertemplate function in the main class
    //And set the template from this function for example.
     $this->setSomeVar();
     echo $this->someVar();
   }
}
```

And then, most importantly, you will have your **routing**:

```
  $noRequest = true;
  $params    = array();
  $class;
  //all routes go from your index.php's location
  $filepath = "application/";
  //Get the requested class and parameters
  $getRequest = explode('/', $request->get('request'));
  //Load homepage if no special request is made
  if( $getRequest[0] == '' ) {
    $page = "home";
  } else {
    //get the class
    $page = rtrim($getRequest[0], '/');
    //Get the called function
    $getFunction = isset( $getRequest[1] ) ? $getRequest[1] : false;
  }
  //Include the requested class. Otherwise, give back a 404
  if( file_exists($filepath . $page . ".php") ) {
    //include the class
    require_once $filepath . $page . ".php";
    //set the class object
    $class = new $page();
  } else {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found", true, 404);
    //TODO:create 404 class
    echo "Page not found";
    exit();
  }

  //There is a function being called, go get it!
  if( $getFunction ) {
    //Make sure you've gotten the parameters as well
    $paramCount = count($getRequest);
    //skip 0 and 1, as those are the class and function
    for( $i = 2; $i < $paramCount; $i++ ) {
      $params[] = $getRequest[$i];
    }
    //Check if method exists
    if( method_exists($class, $getFunction) ) {
      //Always echo the function for returns. This is made for AJAX calls.
      echo call_user_func_array(array(
              $class,
              $getFunction
      ), $params);
    } else {
      die( "function $getFunction was not found in $page" );
    }
    exit();
  } else {
    //No function being called, this has to be a pageload;
    //Don't echo the function because of the templates
    $class->renderTemplate();
  }
```

--
The above is kind of a basic form of how any MVC does it, and it's a dumbed down version of what I've always worked with. Basically, this gives your website one single entry point (the index.php) and makes everything else forbidden. This way, nobody can do anything that your routing will not allow. By having a steady `class->function` routing system, nobody can just go wildly going through your urls, looking for holes.

Your urls from this point on, would look like this:
`http://website.com/page2` would be the class `page2` and do whatever you wanted it to do within said class.

`http://website.com/page2/functionOfPage2Class` could be used for ajax calls.

A sidenote:
This way, you could also call said function classes from within your templates, by simply using `$this->Myfunction();`.

Now, I'm not going to state that this is the best way or the best answer you'll get. The only thing I'll state is that this is approximately what I've worked with so far, and none of my clients have been hacked as far as I know of.

Please, let me know if I did anything wrong or if there are any questions.

### You don't actually need all these classes and such

I thought it would be important to mention that you don't actually have to use this structure I gave you. It is just meant to be an example. Obviously, you can do anything you want, as long as you route whatever you want to do through your `index.php`. That's the entire point of the example scripts.

**Long story short: You put all your php files into a subfolder and deny ALL access to it.**

Comment: ok got it thanks! actually I am not php developer) just waned to ask how you guys do it.